# java 8 grouping a map of same key and value and make a key value pair

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a method `fetchConfigsCount()` which returns `List<Map<String, Object>>`.

The result looks like:

```json
{
    "web_id": "abc",
    "count": 1
},
{
    "web_id": "xyz",
    "count": 1
},
{
    "web_id": "pqr",
    "count": 1
}
```

We have another method `fetchWebsitesCount()` which also returns a response in same format.

`web_id` is the key and its value is owner name.
`count` is another key and its value is of type `int`.

```json
{
    "web_id": "abc",
    "count": 2
},
{
    "web_id": "xyz",
    "count": 3
},
{
    "web_id": "pqr",
    "count": 4
}
```

We have a list of owners which is of type `ArrayList<String>`:

```java
List<String> listOfOwners = ["abc","xyz","pqr"];
```

I want to collect all these things and want to create a result like below:

```json
result:[
    {"owner": "abc",
    "ownerPresence":{
    "configCount":1,
    "websiteCount":2
    },
    {"owner": "xyz",
    "ownerPresence":{
    "configCount":1,
    "websiteCount":3
    },
    {"owner": "pqr",
    "ownerPresence":{
    "configCount":1,
    "websiteCount":4
    }]
```

I am not sure how I can do this in Java 8.

Comment: I'm thinking [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31751554/java-8-streams-merging-a-list-of-maps) should get you up and running...

Comment: Did you try first ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it.

- first, just remap the counts to a `Map<String,List<Integer>>`
- then simply iterate over than map, building the final map and list.

```
List<Map<String, Object>> configCount =
        List.of(Map.of("web_id", "abc", "count", 1),
                Map.of("web_id", "xyz", "count", 1),
                Map.of("web_id", "pqr", "count", 1));

List<Map<String, Object>> webCount =
        List.of(Map.of("web_id", "abc", "count", 2),
                Map.of("web_id", "xyz", "count", 3),
                Map.of("web_id", "pqr", "count", 4));

List<Map<String, Object>> sourceCount =
        List.of(Map.of("web_id", "abc", "count", 22),
                Map.of("web_id", "xyz", "count", 32),
                Map.of("web_id", "pqr", "count", 42));

Map<String, List<Integer>> map = Stream
                .concat(configCount.stream(),
                        Stream.concat(webCount.stream(),
                                sourceCount.stream()))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                mp -> (String) mp.get("web_id"),
                Collectors.mapping(
                        mp -> (Integer) mp.get("count"),
                        Collectors.toList())));
```

The above creates the following where the first `List` values are 'config, website, and source` in that order.

```
pqr=[1, 4, 42]
abc=[1, 2, 22]
xyz=[1, 3, 32]
```

Now instantiate a final List to hold all the maps and finish up.

```
List<Map<String, Object>> result = new ArrayList<>();

for (Entry<String, List<Integer>> e : map.entrySet()) {
    Map<String, Object> tempMap = new HashMap<>();
    tempMap.put("owner", e.getKey());
    tempMap.put("ownerPresence",
            new HashMap<>(Map.of("configCount",e.getValue().get(0),
                                "webSiteCount",e.getValue().get(1),
                                "sourceCount", e.getValue().get(2))));
    result.add(tempMap);
}

result.forEach(mp -> mp.entrySet()
          .forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getKey() + ":" + e.getValue())));
```

prints

```
owner:pqr
ownerPresence:{sourceCount=42, webSiteCount=4, configCount=1}
owner:abc
ownerPresence:{sourceCount=22, webSiteCount=2, configCount=1}
owner:xyz
ownerPresence:{sourceCount=32, webSiteCount=3, configCount=1}
```

Comment: Thanks @WJS...this solution looks working for me but I have 1 question, if I have 1 more method name fetchSourceCount(inventoryOwner) then how I will concate to create a map.

Comment: Sorry that this wasn't more scalable for other data.  But the solution is easy.  Just do something like  `Stream.concat(configCount.stream(),Stream.concat(webCount.stream(),
sourceCount.stream()))`.  But remember that you have to add additional keys for the ownerPresence map.  I will modify my example.  Also, if you have future questions, include information like that so that you get the best possible solution.

Comment: Worked for me, thanks @WJS...It's really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

1. Remap the initial lists of maps into `Map<String, Integer>`:

```java
static Map<String, Integer> convert(List<Map<String, Object>> list) {
    return list
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            m -> (String) m.get("web_id"),
            m -> (Integer) m.get("count")
        ));
}

List<Map<String, Object>> configs  = fetchConfigsCount();
List<Map<String, Object>> websites = fetchWebsitesCount();

Map<String, Integer> configMap  = convert(configs);
Map<String, Integer> websiteMap = convert(websites);
```

2. Create a POJO to represent a list entry:

```java
class Pojo {
    String owner;
    Map<String, Integer> ownerPresence;
    // boilerplate: constructor(s), getters/setters
}
```

3. Stream the list of owners, and build a map:

```java
List<String> listOfOwners = Arrays.asList("abc","xyz","pqr");

List<Pojo> result = listOfOwners
    .stream()
    .map(owner -> new Pojo(
        owner,
        Map.of(
            "configCount",  configMap.get(owner),
            "websiteCount", websiteMap.get(owner)
        )
    ))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

**Update**

If there are other inputs, a wrapper map may be created to hold the converted maps by appropriate keys `"configCount", "websiteCount", "sourceCount"`, etc.:

```java
Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> bigMap = Map.of(
    "configCount",  convert(fetchConfigsCount()),
    "websiteCount", convert(fetchWebsitesCount()),
    "sourceCount",  convert(fetchSourcesCount())
);
```

Then the map for `Pojo` may be created like this:

```java
List<Pojo> result = listOfOwners
    .stream()
    .map(owner -> new Pojo(
        owner,
        bigMap.keySet()
            .stream() // Stream<String>
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                k -> k,
                k -> bigMap.get(k).get(owner)
            )) // Map<String, Integer>
    ))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```